# Why wont my object pass to the d3.hierarchy method?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, d3

I am trying to build a LWC that uses d3 js to build a tree of accounts with related children nodes. I modeled my code after something similiar I found online so it has the lightningElement class at the bottom calling a renderedCallback method which calls a method, makeTree, at the top of the js file. The makeTree method basically has all the logic for the d3 methods etc..

To this point, I have just been using a hardcoded object, treeData (which is at the top commented out), to test out this component. Now I am trying to simulate taking data from the salesforce wire data service and building out an object which will then be passed into the makeTree function. I have put the treeData hardcoded object in the renderedCallback method to just simulate passing data between classes. But, no cigar. It does not populate the tree. When I console.log(JSON.stringify(treeData)) on the makeTree method, it shows up for some reason. But just console.logging the object without stringify, shows nothing. Please help. I am still a beginner so this seems very complex to me although I hope it is something simple I am missing. To recap, how can I pass an object from the lightningElement class to the method makeTree?

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {  loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import ACCOUNTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name'
import D3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/d3';


const makeTree = (div,accountIcon,treeData) => {
/*
var treeData ={
    "name": "Durango Holding",
    "children": [
        { "name": "Lacy Durango",
          "children" : [
              {"name" : "Joint Consumer Checking Account"},
              {"name" : "Savings Account"},
              {"name" : "Greg Durango",
                "children" : [
                    {"name" : "Auto Loan"}
                ]}
          ]
        },
        { "name": "Durango Trucking" },
        { "name": "Durango Leasing",
          "children" : [
              { "name" : "TEF"}
          ] 
        }
     ]
   };
   */
console.log(JSON.stringify(treeData));
console.dir(xa);

console.log(treeData);

var rectHeight = 230;
var rectWidth = 340;

//setting the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right:30, bottom:30, left:2};
var width = 2200 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 1250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Declare a tree Layout and assign its size
var treemap = d3.tree()
        .size([width, height]);

//Assigns the data to hierarchy using parent-child relationships
var nodes = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d){
                return d.children;
            });
console.log(nodes);

//NOTE: This assigns a range of properties to each node including (node.data, node.depth, node.height, node.parent, node.children)
//We are telling the function to use the "children" element from treeData to generate property of the nodes. 

//Map the node data to tree Layout
nodes = treemap(nodes);
console.log(nodes);


//Append the Map(SVG) to the body of the Lightning Component
var svg = d3.select(div)  
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right  )
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 200)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Add All Links between nodes
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(nodes.descendants().slice(1)) //We are not including the main 'root' node as since its drawn from child to parent.
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("fill", "none") //Including all the styles directly here as the Style configured is not applied to lighting component.
        .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
        .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
        .attr("d", function(d){  //Here Attribute 'd' is used to describe the curve. Using Bezier Curve
            return "M" + (d.x + (rectWidth / 2)) + "," + d.y
                + "L" + (d.x + (rectWidth / 2))  + "," + ((d.y + d.parent.y) / 1.69)
                + " " + (d.parent.x  + (rectWidth / 2)) + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 1.69
                + " " + (d.parent.x  + (rectWidth / 2)) + "," + (d.parent.y + rectHeight)
        });
console.log(nodes.descendants());
console.log(nodes.descendants().slice(1));

//Add Each Node as a Group - Ie, setting up a group
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes.descendants())
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "node node--leaf")
                .attr("transform", function(d){
                        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });

var icon = '<div class="slds-media__figure">' +
       '<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon slds-icon-standard-groups" aria-hidden="true">' +
       '<img src={accIcon}alt="">' + '</span>' + '</div>';

node.append("foreignObject")
.attr("width", 350)
.attr("height", 280)
.append("xhtml:div")
.attr("class","box")
.html(function(d) {
    return '<div class="slds-text-align_center slds-text-heading_medium slds-p-around_x-small">Related Accounts</div><br>' +
     '<div class="slds-p-around_small"" style="width:320px">' +
    '<ul class="slds-has-dividers_around-space" style="background-color: white;">' +
    '<li class="slds-item">' +
    '<article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">' + 
    icon +
    '<h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title="Anypoint Connectors">' +
    '<a href="#">' + d.data.name + '</a>' + '</h3>' +'<div class="slds-tile__detail">' +
    '<p class="slds-text-heading_medium">$500,000</p>' +
    '<p class="slds-truncate" title="Company One">' +
    '<a href="#">Company One</a>' +'</p>' + 
    '<p class="slds-truncate" title="Closing 9/30/2015">Closing 9/30/2015</p>' +
    '</div>' +'</article>' +'</li>' +'</ul>' + '</div>';;
});
//.html('<div class="slds-text-heading_large">Durango Trucks</div>');


//Add Text to the node
node.append("text")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("x",48)
.attr("y", function(d){ return d.children ? 20 : 20;})
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) {return d.data.Name; });
}


export default class RelationshipMap extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
accountIcon = D3 + '/account_120.png';
account;
d3Initialized = false;



renderedCallback() {
    if(this.d3Initialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.d3Initialized = true;


    loadScript(this, D3 + '/d3.min.js').then(() => {
        const div = this.template.querySelector('.d3');
        //console.log(this.account);
        var treeData ={
            "name": "Durango Holding",
            "children": [
                { "name": "Lacy Durango",
                  "children" : [
                      {"name" : "Joint Consumer Checking Account"},
                      {"name" : "Savings Account"},
                      {"name" : "Greg Durango",
                        "children" : [
                            {"name" : "Auto Loan"}
                        ]}
                  ]
                },
                { "name": "Durango Trucking" },
                { "name": "Durango Leasing",
                  "children" : [
                      { "name" : "TEF"}
                  ] 
                }
             ]
           };
        makeTree(div, this.accountIcon, treeData);
    })
    .catch(error => window.console.log(error));
}

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ACCOUNTNAME_FIELD]})
account({error, data}){
    if(data){
        this.account = data;
        //console.log(this.account);
    }
};

get accountUrl() {
    return (this.sfdcBaseUrl = window.location.origin + "/" + this.recordId);
}

get accountName() {
    return this.account ? getFieldValue(this.account, ACCOUNTNAME_FIELD) : '';
}
}
```

This is what it should look like:

[image]

```
<template>
<div>
    <div style="float: left;margin-left:15px;">
        <a href={accountUrl}>Back to {accountName}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="d3" lwc:dom="manual">
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
        <span class="slds-icon_container" title="description of icon when needed">
          <div class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-groups" aria-hidden="true">
            <img src={accountIcon}></img>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. Your code is formatted weirdly. Can you share your markup (.html) as well?

Comment: @sfdcfox Ok added. Yea I know it is kinda wierd but I found code online, (which was doing something similiar to using d3 in sf), formatted like this and for some reason if I put the makeTree method within the lightinngElement class, it will not work. Maybe to do with the DOM maniuplation used by d3. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, well, everything appears to be in order. I'll take a closer look tonight/tomorrow as time permits.

Comment: @sfdcfox ok thank you so much. It has been quite the challenge working with d3 in an lwc haha.

Comment: @sfdcfox Just a quick thought... I think you or someone else told me that js in lwc works on reactivity, as in it wont acknowledge changes unless if you use \@track or a method such as map that will re-render things. So since I am using a hardcodded pre-defined object, it wont show up in console.log or be used as in passed to the makeTree method bc I need to "trigger" it to check for changes? Idk if this makes sense but just a thought maybe. I am still very new to javascript/development in general.